# 'Cordova build android' taking too long

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to convert my asp.net files into virtual mobile app with android studio and Cordova. Here is the link that I followed; 
[converting a site into mobile app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JOjHqvOlUs&index=1&list=LL6Z-xt0AqgjPI5y__1NuoFA)

I typed in 'cordova build android' and it has been more than an hour but still not finished yet. Please recommend on how can I continue with this. The screenshot of my cmd is below. Thanks in advance!

[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar9BU.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `November 20, 2015` is demonstrating here?

Comment: It is one of the sdk licenses released date. I couldn't use this built command before since There are errors saying that I have to accept the license agreements. So I was accepting them first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"`Corodva build android`" download multiple dependencies in background.
Reason for being slow may be:
1. Slow Internet.
2. You are under proxy.

If you are not getting any error then cancel this CLI and start another CLI and use same command again.

Another option is .. Open your project in Android Studio and Android Studio will download all dependencies easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! :) yea maybe because of slow internet. Now it has finished. it took 2h 56mins.